# Python: Elegant way to check if at least one regex in list matches a string

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of regexes in python, and a string. Is there an elegant way to check if the at least one regex in the list matches the string? By elegant, I mean something better than simply looping through all of the regexes and checking them against the string and stopping if a match is found.

Basically, I had this code:

```
list = ['something','another','thing','hello']
string = 'hi'
if string in list:
  pass # do something
else:
  pass # do something else
```

Now I would like to have some regular expressions in the list, rather than just strings, and I am wondering if there is an elegant solution to check for a match to replace `if string in list:`.

Comment: python has nothing that does emacs lisp's regexp-opt https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Functions.html

Comment: Why don't you like loops?

Comment: @MartinThoma because it's O(n)

Comment: Then the question should not be for "elegant", but for "less than O(n)".

Comment: a) You mean 'performant' not 'elegant' b) You want to know which individual regex matched (but that doesn't mean you need to iterate over each one individually, which will not be scaleable).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
import re

regexes = [
    "foo.*",
    "bar.*",
    "qu*x"
    ]

# Make a regex that matches if any of our regexes match.
combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regexes) + ")"

if re.match(combined, mystring):
    print "Some regex matched!"
```

Comment: If you don't need to know which one matched, it's better to bracket them with `(?:regex)` instead of `(regex)`

Comment: This method doesn't work if there are more than 100 regexes in the array (Python 2.6). Try nosklo's answer below.

Comment: `regexes = '(?:%s)' % '|'.join(regexes)`

Comment: Any idea why "quax" does not match?

Comment: Because "qu*x" means, q, zero or more u's, and an x.

Comment: in the above answer how can i come to know which regex matched?

Answer (score 105):

```
import re

regexes = [
    # your regexes here
    re.compile('hi'),
#    re.compile(...),
#    re.compile(...),
#    re.compile(...),
]

mystring = 'hi'

if any(regex.match(mystring) for regex in regexes):
    print 'Some regex matched!'
```

Comment: If working in python 2.4, you won't have `any` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785433/python-backports-for-some-methods

Comment: How is this *"something better than simply looping through all of the regexes and checking them against the string and stopping if a match is found"*? I guess the combination of Ned's and this answer could be a winner though...

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I went for based on the other answers:

```
raw_list = ["some_regex","some_regex","some_regex","some_regex"]
reg_list = map(re.compile, raw_list)

mystring = "some_string"

if any(regex.match(mystring) for regex in reg_list):
    print("matched")
```

Answer (score 7):

A mix of both Ned's and Nosklo's answers. Works guaranteed for any length of list... hope you enjoy

```
import re   
raw_lst = ["foo.*",
          "bar.*",
          "(Spam.{0,3}){1,3}"]

reg_lst = []
for raw_regex in raw_lst:
    reg_lst.append(re.compile(raw_regex))

mystring = "Spam, Spam, Spam!"
if any(compiled_reg.match(mystring) for compiled_reg in reg_lst):
    print("something matched")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you loop over the strings, the time complexity would be O(n). A better approach would be combine those regexes as a regex-trie.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def is_matching_any_regex(text, regex_list):
    return text in [re.match(regex, text)[0] for regex in regex_list if re.match(regex, text) is not None]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    regex_list = ['hi', '.*hi.*', '.*me.*', 'me']
    text = "som3th1ng"
    print(is_matching_any_regex(text, regex_list))
    text = "something"
    print(is_matching_any_regex(text, regex_list))
```

output:

```
False
True
```