# python backports for some methods

Tags: python, methods, backport

Is there any backport for the following methods to work with python 2.4:

```
any, all, collections.defaultdict, collections.deque
```

Comment: What saddens me is that I had to look for, found (and appreciate!) this question and the accepted answer today, in 2013. :-]

Comment: The same for me, in 2016 … :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, at least for `any` and `all` it's easy:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False

def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

`deque` is already in 2.4.

As for `defaultdict`, I guess you can emulate that easily with `setdefault()`.

Quoting from Alex Martelli`s (and others') highly recommended [Python Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007973/):

> This is what the setdefault method of
>   dictionaries is for. Say we’re
>   building a word-to-page-numbers
>   index, a dictionary that maps each word
>   to the list of page numbers where it
>   appears. A key piece of code in that
>   application might be:

```
def addword(theIndex, word, pagenumber):
    theIndex.setdefault(word, [ ]).append(pagenumber)
```

> This code is equivalent to more
>   verbose approaches such as:

```
def addword(theIndex, word, pagenumber):
    if word in theIndex:
        theIndex[word].append(pagenumber)
    else:
        theIndex[word] = [pagenumber]
```

> and:

```
def addword(theIndex, word, pagenumber):
    try:
        theIndex[word].append(pagenumber)
    except KeyError:
        theIndex[word] = [pagenumber]
```

Answer (score 5):

As Tim points out, `all` and `any` are trivial. `defaultdict` isn't much more difficult. Here's a passable implementation I believe. It's essentially a translation of the docs into code.

update: removed ternary expression because I remembered that that's not in 2.4

```
class defaultdict(dict):
     def __init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kwargs):
         super(defaultdict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.default_factory = default_factory

     def __missing__(self, key):
         try:
             self[key] = self.default_factory()
         except TypeError:
             raise KeyError("Missing key %s" % (key, ))
         else:
             return self[key]

     def __getitem__(self, key):
         try:
             return super(defaultdict, self).__getitem__(key)
         except KeyError:
             return self.__missing__(key)
```

If you are just using it to build a dict, then you might want to change the EAFP to LBYL for `__getitem__`. right now it's optimized to build the dict and then use it for a while with a lot of non-miss lookups.

<strike>`deque` is going to be tougher. I wish I had the time to do that just because It's probably my favorite out of collections but it's non trivial.</strike> never mind. Just read Tims post all the way through. You got your wish.