# How to check if a line has one of the strings in a list?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

I am trying to find out if there is a nice and clean way to test for 3 different strings.

Basically I am looping trough a file using a `for` loop; then I have to check if it contains 1 of the 3 strings that I have set in a list.

So far I have found the multiple if condition check, but it does not feel like is really elegant and efficient:

```
for line in file
    if "string1" in line or "string2" in line or "string3" in line:
        print "found the string"
```

I was thinking like creating a list that contains `string1`, `string2` and `string3`, and check if any of these is contained in the line, but it doesn't seems that i can just compare the list without explicitly loop trough the list, and in that case I am basically in the same conditions as in the multiple if statement that I wrote above.

Is there any smart way to check against multiple strings without writing long if statements or loop trough the elements of a list?

Comment: Do you need to search every line or just find the first one? If so, you can optimize by breaking out of the for loop.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
for line in file:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        print "yay!"
```

Comment: While the meaning of [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) is pretty logical, I've never used it so I had to look it up.  Nice code @Niklas.

Comment: This behaves almost exactly the same way.

Comment: It's a function. All `any` does is check if any of the values in the sequence is true-ish. The real magic is using a generator expression for the sequence.

Comment: @Niklas B.: Sorry for the late comment, but is there a way to print the string that was found? How would you do this. Thank you.

Comment: @ShankarKumar: I guess something like `next((s in line for s in string), None)` would be useful. I returns the first matched string or `None` otherwise

Comment: I meant `next((s for s in string if s in line), None)`

Comment: @ShankarKumar I think a simple print line instead of print "yay!" will do :)

Comment: @Pitto: How is that any simpler?

Comment: @NiklasB. print line looks to me the shortest and simplest way to print the found string :)

Comment: @Pitto: ah, I only see now that your comment was a response to Shabkar :) However, `line` is not the found string. That would be the matching element of `string`

Comment: You're right: sorry :)

Comment: How would i go about printing the matching string?

`if any(s in line for s in strings): print(s)`

Answer (score 14):

This still loops through the cartesian product of the two lists, but it does it one line:

```
>>> lines1 = ['soup', 'butter', 'venison']
>>> lines2 = ['prune', 'rye', 'turkey']
>>> search_strings = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> any(s in l for l in lines1 for s in search_strings)
True
>>> any(s in l for l in lines2 for s in search_strings)
False
```

This also have the advantage that `any` short-circuits, and so the looping stops as soon as a match is found. Also, this only finds the first occurrence of a string from `search_strings` in `linesX`. If you want to find multiple occurrences you could do something like this:

```
>>> lines3 = ['corn', 'butter', 'apples']
>>> [(s, l) for l in lines3 for s in search_strings if s in l]
[('c', 'corn'), ('b', 'butter'), ('a', 'apples')]
```

If you feel like coding something more complex, it seems the Aho-Corasick algorithm can test for the presence of multiple substrings in a given input string. (Thanks to Niklas B. for pointing that out.) I still *think* it would result in quadratic performance for your use-case since you'll still have to call it multiple times to search multiple lines. However, it would beat the above (cubic, on average) algorithm.

Comment: Actually there is. Check out the Aho-Corasick automaton. It can be done in linear time

Comment: @NiklasB., thanks, that's quite interesting! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the result would still be quadratic, since the OP wants to test multiple lines for substring matches. But that still beats the naive `any` version (cubic, assuming average O(n) performance of `in`).

Comment: No it's linear. Building the automaton is linear time and feeding a string into the automaton is linear time as well

Comment: Or to be more precise, you build the automaton from the needles once and reuse it for every line

Comment: I thought the automaton was built from the needles...

Comment: yeah that's what I meant...

Comment: Ok, but then that's `O(i * (n + m)) + O(s)`, where `i` is the number of input strings, `n` is the average length of an input string, `s` is the total number of characters in the search strings, and `m` is the average number of matches.

Comment: But if you just want a yes/no answer then it's O(s + i*n) = O(s + N) where N is the total input length :P Whatever, the details are not too important

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to combine the search strings into a regex pattern as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3040797/222914).

Comment: I think a regex is prettier, but doesn't regex have quite a lot of overhead? Can it really be more efficient than a simpler 'if ... or ... or ...:' ?

Comment: @SamRedway There is some overhead, but on the other hand the search strings can be combined into one pattern that is processed "in one go".

Comment: @SamRedway Hmm ok, a quick test makes the regex look bad in comparison

Comment: So I would guess that in most use cases readability is more important than efficiency and this is a totally reasonable approach based on that metric. Would say though that the 'more efficient' may be misleading.

Comment: @SamRedway Yeah, edited that out now.