# Going through "Learn Python the hard way." Stuck on ex36. Having issues with an if statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I'll just ask for help on this one function but so far all my functions are having similar issues and I think it has to do with my if statements.

Here's the function:

```
def cosby_room():
    print "You enter a dark room and there is someone sitting alone on a couch."
    print "Oh. It's Bill Cosby. What do ya know?"
    print "He offers you a drink..."
    print "Do you stay or leave?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if "run" or "flee" or "leave" or "dart" or "get out" in choice:
        print "Phew! That was close."
        start()
    elif "stay" or "drink" in choice:
        print "You take a sip."
        print "Everything starts to get all confusing."
        print "Bill whispers something in your ear..."
        print "You pass out and wake up in a park with a strange ache in your butt."
        game_over("At least it'll make for an interesting story.")
    else: 
        cosby_room()
```

So as of now if I run this function, no matter how input for choice, it goes down the first 'if' branch. Even if I type "stay" or "leave" I go down the first branch. I'm not really sure why or what's going on.. Can anyone help me out with this one?

[edit] I do like the solution provided. Is there a way to simplify:

```
if "run" in choice or "flee" in choice or "leave" in choice or "dart" in choice or "get out" in choice:
```

[edit2]

Thanks for the help everyone! I think I have it figured out. Here's the updated code:

```
def cosby_room():
    print "You enter a dark room and there is someone sitting alone on a couch."
    print "Oh. It's Bill Cosby. What do ya know?"
    print "He offers you a drink..."
    print "Do you stay or leave?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    strings = ("run", "flee", "leave", "dart", "get out")
    strings2 = ("stay", "drink")
    for word in choice:
        if any(word in choice for word in strings):
            print "Phew! That was close."
            start()
        elif any(word in choice for word in strings2):
            print "You take a sip."
            print "Everything starts to get all confusing."
            print "Bill whispers something in your ear..."
            print "You pass out and wake up in a park with a strange ache in your butt."
            game_over("At least it'll make for an interesting story.")
        else: 
            cosby_room()
```

Now I just need to learn about 'any'

Comment: your indentation is off

Comment: is there a way to simplify:

if "run" in choice or "flee" in choice or "leave" in choice or "dart" in choice or "get out" in choice:

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8583615/2301450

Comment: The any function.. in the answer provided what does the 's' refer to?