# Identify the matched string from list of strings using any()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

There's a bunch of similar questions that have the same solution: how do I check my list of strings against a larger string and see if there's a match? [How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python) [How to check if a line has one of the strings in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583615/how-to-check-if-a-line-has-one-of-the-strings-in-a-list)

I have a different problem: how do I check my list of strings against a larger string, see if there's a match, and isolate the string so I can perform another string operation relative to the matched string?

Here's some sample data:

```
| id     | data                |
|--------|---------------------|
| 123131 | Bear Cat Apple Dog  |
| 123131 | Cat Ap.ple Mouse    |
| 231321 | Ap ple Bear         |
| 231321 | Mouse Ap ple Dog    |
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to find all instances of "apple" `['Apple', 'Ap.ple', 'Ap ple']` and, while it doesn't really matter which one is matched, I need to be able to find out if `Cat` or `Bear` exist before it or after it. Position of the matched string does not matter, only an ability to determine what is before or after it.

In `Bear Cat Apple Dog` Bear is before Apple, even though Cat is in the way.

Here's where I am at with my sample code:

```
data = [[123131, "Bear Cat Apple Dog"], ['123131', "Cat Ap.ple Mouse"], ['231321', "Ap ple Bear"], ['231321', "Mouse Ap ple Dog"]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'data'])

def matching_function(m): 
     matching_strings = ['Apple', 'Ap.ple', 'Ap ple']

     if any(x in m for x in matching_strings):
          # do something to print the matched string
          return True

df["matched"] = df['data'].apply(matching_function)
```

Would it be simply better to just do this in regex?

Right now, the function simply returns true. But if there's a match I imagine it could also return `matched_bear_before` `matched_bear_after` or the same for Cat and fill that into the df['matched'] column.

Here's some sample output:

```
| id     | data                | matched |
|--------|---------------------|---------|
| 123131 | Bear Cat Apple Dog  | TRUE    |
| 123131 | Cat Ap.ple Mouse    | TRUE    |
| 231321 | Ap ple Bear         | TRUE    |
| 231321 | Mouse Ap ple Dog    | FALSE   |
```

Comment: So you want to know one of the strings appears in the text, *and* you want to extract the word immediately before and after the matching string?

Comment: I would use a regex - you can test for cat and bear next to apple all in one swoop.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know if one of the strings appears in a row, and first check to see if Bear or Cat exists before, then check to see if either exist after

Comment: @kabaname in "Bear Cat Apple Dog" - what would the answer be?

Comment: That would depend on the order of the checking! If I check for Apple, then Bear, then Cat. Then it would print the matched strings in that order. Different order if Cat then Bear, for example. I didn't add examples of other types of "bear" or "cat" as I figured the example implemented solely on "apple" could be reproduced for any string.

Comment: I just want to understand what you mean by "before"

Comment: @shadowtalker I see. Before apple is what I mean, so in "Bear Cat Apple Dog" Bear is before Apple, even though Cat is in the way. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that helps. You should edit that into your question.

Comment: @shadowtalker I will. Thanks!

Comment: Are you only interested in "Bear" and "Cat, or are you interested in *all* other terms that appear before and after?

Comment: Only Bear and Cat. Everything else can be ignored. The idea is to use terms to selectively check and filter rows so that they can be classified.

Comment: Are search terms always separated by whitespace? Other than the whitespace in "Apple" itself.

Comment: yes, they are always separated by whitespace!

Comment: @kabaname Can you include your expected output  for a given dataframe in your question?

Comment: I've adjusted the sample data and sample output to reflect what I would be looking for, for starters. The function simply has to return true if there's a match before and/or after. The critical ability I'm looking for, however, is to simply be able to recognize a string and look for something before or after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to check whether either `Cat` or `Bear` appear before the word of interest, in this case `Apple` or `Ap.ple` or `Ap ple`.

```
^(?:Cat|Bear).*Ap[. ]*ple|Ap[. ]*ple.*(?:Cat|Bear)
```

---

To create the new dataframe column which satisfies the condition, you can combine `map` and `df.str.match`:

```
>>> df['matched'] = list(map(lambda m: "True" if m else "False", df['data'].str.match('^(?:Cat|Bear).*Ap[. ]*ple|Ap[. ]*ple.*(?:Cat|Bear)')))
```

or using `numpy.where`:

```
>>> df['matched'] = numpy.where(df['data'].str.match('^(?:Cat|Bear).*Ap[. ]*ple|Ap[. ]*ple.*(?:Cat|Bear)'),'True','False')
```

will result in:

```
>>> df
       id                data matched
0  123131  Bear Cat Apple Dog    True
1  123131    Cat Ap.ple Mouse    True
2  231321         Ap ple Bear    True
3  231321    Mouse Ap ple Dog   False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the three new columns from the `df['data']` column i.e. `key`, `before` & `after`, then use [`series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) on each of the `before` & `after` columns to find all the matching before and after words:

```
import re

keys = ['Apple', 'Ap.ple', 'Ap ple']
markers = ['Cat', 'Bear']

p =  r'(?P<before>.*?)' + r'(?P<key>' +'|'.join(rf'\b{re.escape(k)}\b' for k in keys) + r')' + r'(?P<after>.*)'
m = '|'.join(markers)

df[['before', 'key', 'after']] = df['data'].str.extract(p)
df['before'] = df['before'].str.findall(m)
df['after'] = df['after'].str.findall(m)

df['matched'] = df['before'].str.len().gt(0) | df['after'].str.len().gt(0)
```

---

```
# print(df)

       id                data       before     key   after  matched
0  123131  Bear Cat Apple Dog  [Bear, Cat]   Apple      []     True
1  123131    Cat Ap.ple Mouse        [Cat]  Ap.ple      []     True
2  231321         Ap ple Bear           []  Ap ple  [Bear]     True
3  231321    Mouse Ap ple Dog           []  Ap ple      []    False
```

Answer (score 0):

python regex find matched string from list

modified your function using regex/walrus operator to simplify:

```
def matching_function(m): 
    matching_strings = ['Apple', 'Ap.ple', 'Ap ple']
    if bool(results := re.search('|'.join(matching_strings), m)):
        print(results[0])
        return True
```