# How to have an operator check if a line in a file being read matches a line in a list or another file being read in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that reads a simple text file to identify lines to copy from a second file. Specifically, I am checking against a file in the FASTA format, which has sequence ID as a line starting with > followed by lines that are a sequence of nucleotides/aminoacids like this:

> >OTU_1
>
> ACTAAACCCATGTTTCCTCGGGG
>
> GATAAGTAAATGAG
>
> GATGA
>
> >OTU_2
>
> GAGATATAGCG

and so on.
So, my 1st file that I am using to search the 2nd Fasta file is effectively as follows

> >OTU_1
>
> >OTU_5
>
> >OTU_35

I have a script that can successfully do what I need it to do, which is go through the fasta and copy the sequence ID and associated sequence if it matches from the first file, except because of how I have the operators, if the 1st file has OTU_1, it takes from the fasta OTU_1, OTU_10, OTU_11, OTU_12, and so on.

The script I tried was

```
`with open("C:/Users/path/keyfile.txt") as f:
    key = f.read().splitlines()
searchfile = open("C:/Users/path/testOTUfasta.txt")
toggle = False
for i in searchfile:
    if (i[0] == ">" and toggle == False):
        if any(s in i for s in key):
            toggle = True
            print(i)
    elif (i[0] == ">" and toggle == True):
        if any(s in i for s in key):
            print(i)
        else:
            toggle == False
    elif toggle == True:
        print(i)`
```

which resulted in the nonspecific selective behavior I described above. I tried to do this based on another [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583615/how-to-check-if-a-line-has-one-of-the-strings-in-a-list).
I also tried

```
`with open("C:/Users/path/keyfile.txt") as f:
    key = f.read().splitlines()
searchfile = open("C:/Users/path/testOTUfasta.txt")
toggle = False
for i in searchfile:
    if (i[0] == ">" and toggle == False):
        if i in key:
            toggle = True
            print(i)
    elif (i[0] == ">" and toggle == True):
        if i in key:
            print(i)
        else:
            toggle == False
    elif toggle == True:
        print(i)`
```

which instead of giving the above result gives nothing.
I am largely confused as to 1. why my if 'i in key' doesn't work and 2. how to better use operators and such to be a bit more specific in the selection.
Thank you for any help
edited 6/26 to fix issues with how the file-examples displayed

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a structured data format, all the more a standardized one,

- use a proper parser to convert file data into a data structure (to avoid reinventing the (square) wheel and ensure that you're reading the format correctly in all possible cases), and
- work with that structure in your code.

For the FASTA format, I could readily find 2 parsers:

- [`SeqIO` from the `BioPython` package](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) (looks like the more mature one, can read other formats and is probably usable by other facilities in the package)
- [`fasta` standalone parser](https://pypi.org/project/fasta/) (likely lacks integration with other stuff but simpler, may be sufficient for your needs)

Answer (score 0):

a quick google of fasta file format shows something a little different from your blockquote, `testOTUfasta.txt` should look something like:

```
>OTU_1
ACTAAACCCATGTTTCCTCGGGG
GATAAGTAAATGAG
GATGA

>OTU_2
GAGATATAGCG

>OTU_10
ACTAAACCCATGTTTCCTCGGGG
GATAAGTAAATGAG
GATGA

>OTU_20
GAGATATAGCG
```

and assuming `keyfile.txt` like this:

```
>OTU_1
>OTU_5
>OTU_20
>OTU_35
```

this setup builds a dictionary (because I am assuming you want to do something with the data other than just print a line) and searches it with the keys from the other file.

```
from pprint import pp

key_file, search_file = 'keyfile.txt', 'testOTUfasta.txt'

with open(search_file) as f1, open(key_file) as f2:
    #build dict with key as line starting with >, value is sequence
    searchfile = {
        k: ''.join(v.replace('\n', ''))
        for k, v in (i.split('\n', maxsplit=1)
        for i in f1.read().split('>') if i)
        }

    pp(searchfile)
    #{'OTU_1': 'ACTAAACCCATGTTTCCTCGGGGGATAAGTAAATGAGGATGA',
    # 'OTU_2': 'GAGATATAGCG',
    # 'OTU_10': 'ACTAAACCCATGTTTCCTCGGGGGATAAGTAAATGAGGATGA',
    # 'OTU_20': 'GAGATATAGCG'}

    #loop through key_file, seach searchfile dict
    for key in (line.strip('>\n') for line in f2):
        if key in searchfile:
            print(key, searchfile[key])
            #do real work here
        else:
            print(key, f'not found in {search_file}.txt')
    #OTU_1 ACTAAACCCATGTTTCCTCGGGGGATAAGTAAATGAGGATGA
    #OTU_5 not found in testOTUfasta.txt.txt
    #OTU_20 GAGATATAGCG
    #OTU_35 not found in testOTUfasta.txt.txt
```

if the fasta files are large-ish and the computer you are using cannot hold the dictionary, the order will have to be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

So partly my bad for using the print version I made of this, but the goal was ultimately to write a new sub-file from the input query.
That said, I got it working, and I don't entirely get WHY it works now when it didn't before, but what worked for me is as follows:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    key = f.read().splitlines()
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as m:
    search = m.read().splitlines()
outfile = open(sys.argv[3], 'w')
toggle = False
for i in search:
    if toggle == False:
        if i in key:
            toggle = True
    if toggle == True:
        if i[0] == ">":
            if i in key:
                outfile.write(i + '\n')
            else:
                toggle = False
        else:
            outfile.write(i + '\n')
```

I figured I should post what worked for me in case if anyone else encounters something like this.