# List containing strings and traditional regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm writing a script to check the contents of files in a directory. What I've got so far is a list with various strings, and would also like to include a traditional regular expression in the search. Here's what I have so far:

```
regex = [ "STRING1", "STRING2", "STRING3", (?:<my regex here>)]
pattern = re.compile(regex)
```

I'm getting various errors and have tried trouble shooting it a bit, prepending r' to the regex, using .join() in the compile function, clearly I'm doing something wrong. The code executes properly but does not find matches when it should, so obviously my regex is being compiled incorrectly. So what is the correct way to make a list of the regexes I want to use, and then iterate over that list in my search?

Comment: I think you might need to join the list, like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3040797/264775

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please use tags and don't prepend the language to your title.

Comment: What do you want your example to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?:

```
import re

# Pre-compile the patterns
regexes = [ re.compile(p) for p in [ 'this',
                                     'that',
                                     ]
            ]
text = 'Does this text match the pattern?'

for regex in regexes:
    print 'Looking for "%s" in "%s" ->' % (regex.pattern, text),

    if regex.search(text):
        print 'found a match!'
    else:
        print 'no match'
```

It was taken from [PyMOTW](http://pymotw.com/2/re/index.html#module-re).